# Merge multiple queries from MoreLikeThis.like and do a new search

Tags: lucene

I am using the lucene 3.0.2 framework for a little project. I need to create new queries, on relevant documents (multiple) and do a new search that is more relevant to the chosen documents.

So far I have added all the documents marked from the user into a ArrayList`<Document>`, and then created an ArrayList`<Query>` with queries that MoreLikeThis.like(docId) created for me.

Now, with all these new queries from the relevant documents, I need to somehow merge them. Problem is that Query can not cast to BooleanQuery, and the only method I find for merging queries is Query.mergeBooleanQueries, but nothing about just Query.

Any tips? :)

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
The instance-method combine will worked. Strange this isn't a static method tho.